# Can I combine querydsl-jpa and querydsl-sql to create incremental changes to the underlying database?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, database-migration, querydsl

We have an ongoing project in which we use querydsl-jpa to make the queries. 
When we deploy a new version of the product, it auto-executes sql file scripts to update the tables before starting hibernate. This scripts are just sql strings manually crafted (and very error prone).

I would like to use querydsl-sql to write the migration scripts programmatically and once that's done, use querydsl-jpa for normal ORM querying.

So the question is, if anyone knows if they can live together in the same project? And if anyone has done that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Querydsl JPA and SQL in a project together is a very common use case. You can for example use the JPA API and Querydsl JPA for CRUD use cases and Querydsl SQL for queries.

Querydsl SQL doesn't support DDL scripts (CREATE, ALTER etc). So that part is not covered by Querydsl.